# Is there any update to fix the warning 'ViewPager Android has been extracted from react-native core'?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-navigation

When I use **react-navigation** to implement the **createMaterialTopTabNavigator** it works fine for iOS but for Android it throws a warning stating that **ViewPager Android will be removed in future release and asking me to use imported from "@react-native-community/viewpager' instead of react-native**. Im sure this warning is from the react-navigation package and changes need to be done in react-navigation package to fix it.

But I don't see any open issue in their GitHub page regarding this or  is this a common update issue? Do I have to wait for their update in their next release?

[image: Android-React-Native]

Answer (score 1):

Here's the issue thread about this in `react-navigation` which has unfortunately been closed without a resolution yet. Here's the suggested workaround to suppress that particular warning from: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/5730#issuecomment-518372933

You can hide the yellow box for this warning in the meantime by doing this at the root level of your app:

```
import { YellowBox } from "react-native"

YellowBox.ignoreWarnings([
  "Warning: ViewPagerAndroid has been extracted",
])
```

Comment: Hardly an ideal solution